# using nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I know this question has been asked and I have read through them but I still can't get this to work.

I want to do the following:

```
bigDict={'AABAA':{'00500':4, '00110':1, '00001':1}, 'AAAAA':{'03300':15, '03110':10, '00401':1}, 'BBBBB':{'11500':1, '11110':1, '11111':1}}
```

the numbers WITHOUT quotes, 4,1,1,15,10,1,1,1,1 are the COUNTS of those strings which are part of the larger string.

Is this possible in python using nested dictionary? Thank you

I use a sliding window move along a string like AAAABBBBBBLLLLLLAAA and once I find the 5 seq length string for example AABAA, I take that and find the corresponding "number" seq '00500', if I encounter another AABAA then I extract the number seq for that, and if that is again 00500, I now increase the counter for 00500 to 2 from 1

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Are you generating this dictionary from the larger string you referenced, generating the larger string from this dictionary, something else?

Comment: you could use Counters instead of those inner dicts, but appart from that, I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes is it possible. Your snippet is valid and legit python.

Comment: yes exactly, I use a sliding window move along a string like AAAABBBBBBLLLLLLAAA and once I find the 5 seq length string for example AABAA, I take that and find the corresponding "number" seq '00500', if I encounter another AABAA then I extract the number seq for that, and if that is again 00500, I now increase the counter for 00500 to 2 from 1...

Comment: I know its valid to have such a structure but I don't know how to create it in python.

Comment: Can you explain where you're getting those number sequences from? I don't understand the relationship between 'AABAA' and '00500', '00110' and '00001'.

Comment: Its two sequences the second one connected to the first one with one-to-one correspondence. AAAAABBBBBAAAAABBBBBLLLLL  corresponds to another seq made up of numbers like this 1111111111000005555511111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bigDict = {}
```

then when you have a letter label and number ...

```
bigDict.setdefault(label, {}).setdefault(num, 0)
bigDict[label][num] += 1
```